# How to check if a neighbourhood of at least five elements of an array satisfies a criterion?

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing

I have a numpy array, and I check for local minima which are lower than a threshold (mean value - 3 * standard deviation). Out of those minima I want to select those which are in the neighbourhood of at least five points which are all below the threshold value. If a certain neighbourhood contains multiple minima, I want to know which minimum has the lowest value. How to do this and make it run relatively fast?

Code similar to the one suggested by B.M. doesn't quite do what I need.

```
from numpy import *

a=random.rand(10)
n = ones(7)
threshold=0.5
u=convolve(a<t,n,'same')
```

This is what it produced:
x
array([ 0.6034448 ,  0.16098872,  0.39563129,  0.33611677,  0.90138981,
        0.26088853,  0.45720198,  0.100786  ,  0.47705187,  0.15514734])
u
array([ 3.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  5.,  5.,  4.])

Which suggests that element at index 6 is part of a neighbourhood of 6 points below the threshold value. I guess it also counted element with index 3, which is not desirable behaviour, as there is value > 0.9 at position 4. And element at position 9 claims to be in a group of 4 elements, while I would say it is a group of 5.

This is my current solution to the problem:

```
    layer = Xa
    while layer > overlap:
        if d[layer] > d[layer+1] and d[layer] > d[layer-1]:
            if layer > 300:
                threshold = threshold_free
            else:
                threshold = threshold_PBL
            if d[layer] <= threshold:
                upper_limit = layer
                lower_limit = layer

                k = 1
                kp = 0
                while kp < k and layer + kp < Xa:
                    kp = k
                    if d[layer+k] <= threshold:
                        upper_limit = layer + k
                        k += k
                k = 1
                kp = 0
                while kp < k and layer - kp > overlap:
                    kp = k
                    if d[layer-k] <= threshold:
                        lower_limit = layer - k
                        k += k

                transition_interval = upper_limit - lower_limit
                if transition_interval >= 5:
                    print layer, upper_limit, lower_limit, upper_limit - lower_limit
                    layer = lower_limit
                    if valid_time in layers:
                        layers[valid_time].append(layer)
                    else:
                        layers[valid_time] = [layer]
        layer -= 1
```

Comment: Could you show what you've tried and the problems/errors you are encountering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tricks to do that:

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from scipy.signal import convolve2d 
from scipy.ndimage.filters import minimum_filter as mini

a=random.rand(100,100)
neighbours = ones((3,3))
threshold=0.2
u=convolve2d(a<threshold,neighbours,'same')
mins=((u>=6)*(a<threshold))
minis=mini(choose(mins,(1,a)),size=(3,3))==a

subplot(121);imshow(mins,cmap=cm.gray_r,interpolation='none')
subplot(122);imshow(minis,cmap=cm.gray_r,interpolation='none')
```

this script produce:
[image: minimuns]

On the left figure those who have 5 neighbours, on the right only the min is selected.  If you want the indices and values, use `inds=mask_indices(100,lambda x,k: minis)` and  `a[inds]` .

Comment: Thank you, I tried this, but it didn't quite work as I needed.